# MS Word 2007 - Insert shape but keep that tool selected

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I am making a flow chart in Word 2013 which involves adding a lot of arrows. At the moment I have to do it like this:

- Select arrow tool
- Draw arrow
- Select arrow tool
- Draw arrow

Is there a way to keep it selected so that I can draw many arrows without having to reselect it?
You know, like hold down ctrl while drawing or something. It isnt shift either.

Thanks!

PS don't recommend another program, I'm interested in office/word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you choose the arrow from "Insert->Shapes", right-click it and choose "Lock Drawing Mode". Then the tool won't deselect after each arrow.

[image: screenshot of lock drawing mode]