# macOS MS Powerpoint 2019 - Insert shape but keep that tool selected

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Previous Post but not for macOS.

[MS Word 2007 - Insert shape but keep that tool selected](https://superuser.com/questions/887407/ms-word-2007-insert-shape-but-keep-that-tool-selected)

Is there a version of this for the Mac a way to keep it selected in power point so that I can draw many arrows without having to reselect it? You know, like hold down Ctrl while drawing or something. It isn't shift either.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid Office for mac does not have such a feature to fix the selection of a shape.

Here is a similar thread on UserVoice forum, "[Lock drawing mode](https://word.uservoice.com/forums/304942-word-for-mac/suggestions/38405854-lock-drawing-mode)". You could vote it up to make this voice louder.

Answer (score 0):

#### How can I Insert shape but keep that tool selected?

Use Lock Drawing Mode.

> To lock a shape you need to go to the auto shapes menu, right click on
> the shape and choose "Lock Drawing Mode" option.
>
> [image: Lock Drawing Object MenuLock Drawing Object Menu]
>
> The cursor turns into a cross. You can draw the shape as many times as
> you want without the cursor reverting to its original form.
>
> To get out of the "Lock Drawing Mode" click on the shape by going to
> auto shapes menu.
>
> This simple option saves you a whole lot of time while creating
> complex diagrams, flow charts, background designs etc.

Source: [Save time using Lock Drawing Objects Tool In PowerPoint](https://www.all-ppt-templates.com/lock-drawing-object-in-powerpoint.html)

Comment: thanks for the share. But I was looking for a macOS equivalent.  That's windows.